# Images not loading in Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

HTML File :

```
 <div>
      <img  src="New-Google-Logo.png"/>
    </div>
```

Here the New-Google-Logo.png is in the same folder as in the html file. But after ng serve the html page loads with other details, but not the image. Tried by directly giving a link for an image (like www.google.com/images/x.png), it works, but local file is not loading.

Folder Tree :

```
src
  -app
    -logincomponent
              - logincomponent.html
              - logincomponent.css
              - New-Google-Logo.png
              - logincomponent.ts
     -homecomponent
              - homecomponent.html
              - homecomponent.css
              - homecomponent.ts
```

Here the New-Google.png is referred inside logincomponent.html as given above.

Try 2 :

```
src
  -app
    -logincomponent
              - logincomponent.html
              - logincomponent.css
              - Images
                - New-Google-Logo.png
              - logincomponent.ts
```

And referred in the html like :

```
<div>
      <img  src="./images/New-Google-Logo.png"/>
 </div>
```

Both these didn't worked out.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: can you add you folder tree

Comment: @ovokuro yes, I am getting error like failed to load resource : at http://localhost:4200/New-Google-Logo.png

Comment: Is the image in the right folder? Is it a png?

Comment: @Robert I have edited the question with folder tree, please have a look and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ovokuro I have edited the question with folder tree, kindly have a look.

Comment: <img alt="" class="" src="app/logincomponent/images/New-Google-Logo.png"> and in your angular-cli.json "prefix": "app"

Comment: @Amal check and let me know

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are using angular-cli then all your static assets should be kept in assets folder. Then you should give path as

```
 <div>
      <img  src="assets/images/New-Google-Logo.png"/>
 </div>
```

When you serve the project all static assets needs to be served to client in order to display it on client. Angular cli build and bundle entire project in js files. To serve your static assets you can follow two ways

- put all your static assets in assets folder which angular-cli serves with default .angular-cli.json
- or you need to make entry of the static assets folder in .angular-cli.json file in array named as assets as my images folder is in static folder and static folder is at same hierarchy level of assets folder

  ```
  "assets": [ "assets", "static/images" ]
  ```

Comment: I am using angular cli, but not making use of assets. Is it mandatory? Like I was using the same project like few days before and all worked fine. Today I reinstalled the cli , then onwards getting this problem.Kindly guide me through how to rectify.
Thanks

Comment: When you serve the project all static assets needs to be served to client in order to display it on client. Angular cli build and bundle entire project in js files. To serve your static assets you can follow two ways
- put all your static assets in assets folder which angular-cli serves with default .angular-cli.json
-or you need to make entry of the static assets folder in .angular-cli.json file in array named as assets as my images folder is in static folder and static folder is at same hierarchy level of assets folder 

"assets": [
  "assets",
  "static/images"
]

Comment: I tried making a folder in the logincomponent folder named images and put the image there and tried as well, but no luck. After that it looked like as I added in the try 2 section in the question.

Comment: In order to serve static content from different folder you need to add that folder's path in `assets` array of `.angular-cli.json` and don't give relative path in src. in your case just give it as `<div> <img src="Images/New-Google-Logo.png"/> </div>`
and add 

`"assets": [ "assets", "logincomponent/Images" ]`

Comment: Check this link for your reference https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration

Comment: I tried using assets, interestingly this works when I put the images inside the src folder (not inside app/logincomponent/images) and added in assets as "assets": [ "assets", "New-Google-Logo.png" ], but when I tried like "assets": [ "assets", "app/logincomponent/Images" ] and referring in html as you said , its not working.

Comment: can you try one thing

`"assets": [
 { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./app/logincomponent/Images", "output": "./logincomponent/" },
]`

and then 

`<div> <img src="logincomponent/New-Google-Logo.png"/> </div>`

Answer (score 1):

change path to

```
<img  src="assets/images/New-Google-Logo.png"/>
```

and add height and width

```
 <img  src="assets/images/New-Google-Logo.png" width="200" height="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create project using CLI you will have one assets folder just create one image folder inside it and paste your all images inside it of .png type then give
reference src="assets/images/AnyImage.png" inside your html  it will load the images. Actually you pasted your images inside loginComponent folder. Try this it will work.

Answer (score 0):

if you have references like this in your css files where images are referenced as below

```
    .topmenu a:hover {
    background:url('../images/topm_bg_right.gif') right top no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
   }
 then you may have to add the image extension wild cards in the permit all list of your 
 WebSecurityConfig class as shown.. especially when you have bundled your app with both angular and spring boot together ng build and moved to the static folder

 .antMatchers("/","/*.jpg","/*.png",
                    "/home","/assets/**",
                    "/polyfills.js",).permitAll()
```