# Angular 7 problem with component to show image on html. Why isn't the image showing?

Tags: html, angular, image, typescript, angular6

I am doing a click cat game, and when I put the path of the image of the cat in the component's template using img, the image does not appear when running the page.

I tried to use the img as property using [img]="path", and also enter the path directly to the img element

Template:

```
<div>{{catName1}}</div>
<div>
    <img src="./image/cat.jpg" (click)="clickUp()">
</div>
<div>{{catClick1}}</div>
</div>
```

Typescript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  catName1 = 'Misho';
  catImg1 = 'image/cat.jpg';
  catClick1 = 0;

  clickUp(){
    this.catClick1 += 1;
  }

}
```

[How it is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z44gt.png)

[Folder of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce1Q1.png)

Comment: where's your image folder? can you take a picture of your folders?

Comment: I added the picture, see above.

Comment: Check out this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920722/images-not-loading-in-angular-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920722/images-not-loading-in-angular-2)

Comment: You should put the image in `assets` and the image source should be `assets/image/cat.jpg`. You don't want the image in your `app` folder.

Comment: ok, thank you I will try that

Comment: It worked!!! thank you!!!

Comment: The problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything's fine with your code.

Just move your image folder from

> `/src/app/image`

to

> `/src/assets`

directory & do change the `src` in

> app.component.html