# CSS and Images not loading in Spring Boot's index.html

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot

My files are organized like this:

[image]

`index.html` renders perfectly when accessed via Intellij's lunch url (`localhost:63342/../static/index.html`)

But when I run my Spring Boot app and access `http://localhost:8080/`, my `index.html` fails to load the CSS files and images.

I have not touched any other configuration. All my controllers are `@RestController`s. I do have `mustache` installed as a dependency but am not using it anywhere.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/body.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/section_one.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/section_two.css"/>
    </head>
    <body class="body-inner-wrap">
        <header>
            <div id="header-wrapper">

                <div id="title" class="main_title">
                    <h1>Project</h1>
                </div>

                <div id="links">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#Join"><b>Join</b></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#Howto"><b>How-To</b></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#About"><b>About</b></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="intro-box">
                <h2>A simple and fast platform to upload audio files and reach out to your listeners via
                    our no non-nonsense mobile apps.</h2>

                <h5>This is work in progress and will be live soon as a closed beta.</h5>
            </div>

            <div id="login-box">
                <div class="login-form">
                    <form method="post" action="">
                        <p><input type="text" name="Username" value="" required placeholder="Username"></p>
                        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" required placeholder="Password"></p>
                        <p><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br><br>

        <div id="device-mock-bg">
            <div class="device-mock">
                <img src="images/android-device-mock.svg"
                     alt="Android app mock up"
                     height="700"
                     width="300" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, checking the browser's console I found these -

`The resource from “http://localhost:8080/css/style.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“application/json”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)`

`Cookie “JSESSIONID” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://localhost:8080/css/style.css” because the scheme does not match.`

Any help, please?

Comment: can you share your index.html where you have referenced css

Comment: Done. Have added some errors from the console too.

Comment: Strangely with same `index.html` and directory structure, it's working for me. From the error message, it seems somehow response header `content-type` is getting set as `application/json` on url `http://localhost:8080/css/style.css`  instead of `text/css`. Are you  setting global content type header for all urls in your configurations.

Comment: Spring security was the problem for me. I had to explicitly allow `css/*` in security configs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920722/images-not-loading-in-angular-2/68203636#68203636

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Spring Security was blocking all resources. Had to configure it to allow `/css/*` and `/images/*`

Answer (score 0):

Next to the comment by @krtkush, I had migrated my application from MVC to a SPA using VueJS. I had a custom MvcConfig (extending WebMvcConfigurer) class configured which resulted in problems loading only my CSS files, Javascript was loading just fine. I had some overrides for: addResourceHandlers, addInterceptors and added a message source for internationalisation.

After having deleted this class, as I didn't need it anymore, I found that this resolved my CSS loading issue. This unfortunately took me longer than I had hoped for. Hope this helps others that are in a similar process.